# Is there a way to get updated date of an iOS app version using App Store Connect REST API?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

We want to show when the app's version was updated. AppStoreConnect REST API response doesn't contain the updated date of the version.

Using `apps/{app_store_id}/appStoreVersions` to fetch app versions of an app. It gives the payload of a single version as below:

```
"attributes": {
    "platform": "IOS",
    "versionString": "2.6.4",
    "appStoreState": "REJECTED",
    "appVersionState": "REJECTED",
    "copyright": "",
    "reviewType": "APP_STORE",
    "releaseType": "AFTER_APPROVAL",
    "earliestReleaseDate": null,
    "usesIdfa": null,
    "downloadable": true,
    "createdDate": "2024-03-05T04:08:51-08:00"
},
```

Here createdDate is the date of the version creation with status "PREPARE_FOR_SUBMISSION".

Want to show the status with its updated date as attached picture.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I only see [List All App Store Versions for an App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/list_all_app_store_versions_for_an_app) as giving any information regarding your application updates.

You would need to approximate the "updated date" by monitoring changes to other fields that are likely to change upon an app update.

You could try and:

- fetch app versions using the `apps/{id}/appStoreVersions` endpoint.
- for each version, examine the associated `build` relationship.
- use the [`builds` endpoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/list_all_builds_of_an_app) (assuming one exists that allows fetching by ID) to get details about the build, specifically looking for an upload date (field '`uploadedDate`') or similar timestamp.

That would assume that new builds correlate closely with version updates, which is often — but not always — the case.

---

> We want to show the version status history with updated time.

I do not see that directly available through the API. You would need to implement a system to manually record the dates of status changes whenever you check the App Store Connect dashboard.
You could automate the retrieval of this data through web scraping (if it does not violate any term of service).

Comment: this is not working. Updated the question with picture. We want to show the version status history with updated time.